# Struts2 <s:bean/> tag, used to instanciate a Parametric Bean

Tags: java, generics, struts2

After looking a while other google, and the web, I decided to post my question here.

The question is quite really basic, and simple :

How do I use the struts2 tag `<s:bean ... />` to instanciate a Parametric Bean ?

For example imagine I have :

`public class GenericBean<T> {
...`

How will I instanciate this bean with a `BeanType` for instance, inside a jsp using struts 2 ?

`<s:bean name="GenericBean" var="myBean"/>`

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can write this :

```
<s:bean name="GenericBean" var="myBean"/>
```

And the only thing is that in the ***methods*** of **GenericBean** *where I need the Type of* , *the "invoker"* **should provide the corresponding** class for .